# Transparent Checkbox in Custom Control Using C#

Tags: c#, controls, transparency, mouseover

I have created a custom control that gets highlighted when the mouse hovers over it.  The custom control also has a checkbox.  When the mouse goes over the checkbox, the highlighting of the custom control does not occur.  I've tried using **WS_EX_TRANSPARENT** on the checkbox but it isn't working for me.

```
        int cbStyle = GetWindowLong(CompletedCheckBox.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        SetWindowLong(CompletedCheckBox.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, cbStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transparent only affects drawing, not mouse events. The check box is getting the mouse events, this in turn means that when you mouse over the checkbox, your control receives a MouseLeave event.  To ensure that the background color changes, even when a child control ( at any level) gets a MouseEnter event, you need to track that a control of interest -- or any child, grand-child ..etc-- has the mouse over it.  To do this, recurse through all descendant controls and intercept the appropriate events for them. To do this, try something similar to the class below.

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AttachMouseEnterToChildControls(this);
    }

    void AttachMouseEnterToChildControls(Control con)
    {
        foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
        {
            c.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(control_MouseEnter);
            c.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(control_MouseLeave);
            AttachMouseEnterToChildControls(c);
        }
    }
    private void control_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    }

    private void control_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }
}
```